# How to use Dynamic with ArrayPlot or similar inside Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, color

I have some complicated data to calculate and display. I want to change the display inside `Manipulate` with a control variable and use `Dynamic` to avoid recalculating the data. For example, Mma documentation gives this, which works beautifully:

```
Manipulate[
 data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
 Graphics[{Point[Dynamic[data^p]]}, AspectRatio -> 1], {n, 100, 5000, 
  1}, {p, 0.1, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

But if I try

```
Manipulate[
 data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
 ArrayPlot[Dynamic[data^p]], {p, 0.1, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

it gives an error. The same happens with `(List)DensityPlot`. It will not work either if I try to just change the `ColorFunction` inside `Dynamic`. Nor do I see how to recalculate what to plot outside the Plot but inside a `Dyanmic`.

**EDIT**

I need to `Show` the `ArrayPlot` together with a `Graphics` object. For example, this does not work:

```
Manipulate[data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
 Show[Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p], Graphics[Circle[]]], {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

**Second edit**

The real problem seems to be that I have a `Block` inside my `Manipulate`, and then the local variable I use for data turns red when I try to put it inside a `Dynamic`, indicating it may not work even before I try. Example:

```
Manipulate[Module[{data}, data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
  Dynamic@
   Show[ArrayPlot[data^p], Graphics[Circle[]]], {p, 
  0.1, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

I have discovered that it is impossible to update local variables; see [this doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html). I have asked another question specific to this issue [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237939/14118).

Comment: Revers `ArrayPlot` and `Dynamic` line `Dynamic[ArrayPlot[..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Edit**

Maybe use `With`

```
Manipulate[With[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]},
  Dynamic@Show[ArrayPlot[data^p], Graphics[Circle[]]]], {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

**Edit**

```
Manipulate[data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
 Dynamic@Show[ArrayPlot[data^p], Graphics[Circle[]]], {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

**Original**

```
Manipulate[data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
 Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p], {p, 1, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

Comment: Thank you for the very fast answer. In fact, I need to edit my question, because I need to `Show` the `ArrayPlot` together with a `Graphics` object, and your answer will not work,

Comment: Your edited response is also correct and very fast, but, again, I need to modify my question. I tried to make it as simple as possible, but evidently I have not yet captured the real difficulty. When I figure it out, I will edit again.

Comment: The suggestion to use `With` will not allow further change of data; the final values would have to be set within the initial assignment.

Comment: @RussLyons there is nothing preventing this when using `With`. It would make for better responses if you can be more clear about what you mean when you say “the final values” and to clarify how you would like to have a “change of data”.

Comment: @CATrevillian I think you are right. I can compute `data`, then use `With[{d=data} ... d ...]` with a new dummy variable `d` and not use `data` in the plot. Thanks.