# Accommodating local variables within Dynamic

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, localization

I would like to use a local variable within `Dynamic`, but that may not work, and the front end will show the local variable in red to give a warning. However, if I define a global variable to equal the local one, then I can use the global one inside `Dynamic`. Will this always work, or is it just a way to hide a problem that may occur? For example, this works:

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]}, dataG = data; 
  Dynamic@ArrayPlot[dataG^p]], {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

(In the present example, since the only effect on the plot of changing `p` is to change the color, one could also use `ColorFunction`.)

I stripped away many details from the application I have in mind. Rather than a simple `data`, I have a complicated calculation to do that depends on other control variables of the `Manipulate`. And that is the other reason for using `Dynamic` and why I want the local variable to be defined within `Manipulate`.

If this will not always work, is there a convenient way to introduce global variables so that they do not conflict with other global variables in the same session and without having to remember or check what has been used already?

Comment: Does the further scoping have to be *inside* Manipulate? Otherwise you could wrap the `Manipulate[ArrayPlot[...], ...]` in a scoping construct, eg `Module`, `DynamicModule`, or `With` (but not Block): `Module[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]}, Manipulate[ArrayPlot[data^p], {p, 0.1, 10}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]]`. You won’t need Dynamic inside this way.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, it does have to be inside. I stripped away many details from the application I have in mind. Rather than a simple `data`, I have a complicated calculation to do that depends on other control variables of the `Manipulate`. And that is the other reason for using `Dynamic`.

Comment: I see. Please add that constraint and context to the question.

Comment: I'd use `With` on the example: `Manipulate[With[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]},
  Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p]], {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think I can use `With` because I need to to some calculations before I obtain the value of `data`, and these depend on other control variables.

Comment: If you don't alter `data` after first computing it (in a given dynamic update), then I think you could use `With` as I did. But without code, I can really only *imagine* that it's always possible.  An alternative is a local variable with no control attached to it: `Manipulate[
 data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
 Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p], {p, 0.1, 10}, {data, None}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I need other local variables in order to calculate `data`, so I don't see how to do that. OTOH, your no-control approach seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two alternatives:

Using `With` (use multiple ones if necessary):

```
Manipulate[
 With[
  {data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]},   
  Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p]],
 {p, 0.1, 10}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

Use a local variable with no control:

```
Manipulate[ 
 data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]; 
 Dynamic@ArrayPlot[data^p],
 {p, 0.1, 10},
 {data, None}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

One advantage of `With` is that it does not create a tracked symbol, which sometimes simplifies the `Dynamic` behavior of the `Manipulate`.  Two disadvantages of `With` are that the variable is constant, and many nested `With` are inelegant.

Comment: The first does not have a footprint on the notebook size out of the box, the second one requires `UnsavedVariables`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. I thought I was going to say that, except about `UnsavedVariables`.  That option had eluded my attention, maybe because I stopped contributing to the demonstrations project around the time V8 came out.